# How to define optional arguments in a function

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function to get some descriptive stats from a data frame. The function takes three argument: data set, set of numerical variables, set of character variables. I managed to write the function to successfully obtain the required result when the both numerical and character variables are identified within the argument. However, when one of these argument is missing, I'd like the function to return a list with two components with the missing argument as NULL within its component.

Here's the code I've written. Please let me know if you have an answer.

```
table1 <- function(dat, numvar, charvar){
  result_n <- numeric()
  result_c <- data.frame()
  #This is the original table function for numerical values
  for (i in 1:length(numvar)) {
    new_row <- c(round(mean(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2) ,
                 round(median(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2),
                 round(sd(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2),
                 length(dat[[numvar[i]]])-sum(is.na(dat[[numvar[i]]])),
                 sum(is.na(dat[[numvar[i]]])))
    result_n <- rbind(result_n,new_row)
  }
  rownames(result_n) <- numvar
  colnames(result_n) <- c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "N", "N_miss")
  #Thisi is the new table for char values
  for (i in 1:length(charvar)) {
    tab.dat <- as.data.frame(table(dat[charvar[i]],useNA = "ifany" ))
    a1 <- as.character(tab.dat$Var1)
    a1[3] <- "NMiss"
    one.table <- data.frame(
      Varname = c(charvar[i], rep(" ", nrow(tab.dat)-1)),
      group = a1,
      count= tab.dat$Freq)
    result_c <- rbind(result_c, one.table)
  }
  result_list <- list(numericStats = result_n, FactorStats =result_c)
  return(result_list)
}
```

Comment: You can check if a function argument is missing with `?missing`. No joke. `if(!missing(numvar)){for loop code block; assign names to result_n}`.

Comment: Very useful function thank you very much. It worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value to a function:

```
table1 <- function(dat = NULL, numvar = NULL, charvar = NULL) {...
```

From there, the script can determine which is missing and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already knew how to set the default value of argument to NULL. However, the code needs modification to adjust the output value to display NULL under the same structure

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
table1 <- function(dat, numvar=NULL, charvar=NULL){
  result_n <- numeric()
  result_c <- data.frame()
  #This is the original table function for numerical values
  #I borrowed builtin function (ifmissing) from the internet
  if(!missing(numvar)) {for (i in 1:length(numvar)) {
    new_row <- c(round(mean(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2) ,
                 round(median(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2),
                 round(sd(dat[[numvar[i]]],na.rm = T),2),
                 length(dat[[numvar[i]]])-sum(is.na(dat[[numvar[i]]])),
                 sum(is.na(dat[[numvar[i]]])))
    result_n <- rbind(result_n,new_row)
  }
    rownames(result_n) <- numvar
    colnames(result_n) <- c("Mean", "Median", "SD", "N", "N_miss")}
  #Thisi is the new table for char values
  #I borrowed builtin function (ifmissing) from the internet
  if(!missing(charvar)) {for (i in 1:length(charvar)) {
    tab.dat <- as.data.frame(table(dat[charvar[i]],useNA = "ifany" ))
    a1 <- as.character(tab.dat$Var1)
    a1[3] <- "NMiss"
    one.table <- data.frame(
      Varname = c(charvar[i], rep(" ", nrow(tab.dat)-1)),
      group = a1,
      count= tab.dat$Freq)
    result_c <- rbind(result_c, one.table)
  }}
  result_list <- list(numericStats = result_n, FactorStats =result_c)
  return(result_list)
}
```